# UIBezzierPath for rounded rectangles

Tags: ios, swift

I am using UIBezzierPath to draw a circle arround a frame using this

```
 let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: (frame.size.width - 10)/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)
```

I want to do the same but instead of circle i want to draw a rounded rectangle.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using `UIBezierPath` as-

```
CAShapeLayer * maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: self.bounds byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii: (CGSize){10., 10.}].CGPath;

self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Also you can do so by setting corner radius on layer of view as-

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
view.layer.borderWidth = 1
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should be working for you:

```
let side = self.view.frame.size.width - 10
let cornerRadius = 5
let rectPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, side, side), cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
```